# Insertar usuarios en un select

Tags: nodejs

Tengo esta consulta

```
getAnalisisDetalladoSelect: function(req, res, next){
        sql.connect(config)
            .then(function() {
                var usuarios = null;
                var request = new sql.Request();
                request.query("SELECT Sk_Codigo_Usuario from Sk_Usuarios")
                    .then(function(recordset) {
                        usuarios = recordset['recordset'];
                        console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
                        console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
                        sql.close();
                        res.render('menu/analisisDetallado', { ListUsuario: usuarios });

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Request error: ' + err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
                }
            });

    }
```

La cual me trae los usuario y debo ingresarlos en un select

```
td
  select(name="myselection")
      each option, Usuarios in ListUsuario
        option(value= "#{Usuarios.Sk_Codigo_Usuario}") option
```

alguna ayuda de como poner el each para llenar el select

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar como intentas llenar tu select?

Comment: Listo, ya lo puse

Comment: Ya puse un ejemplo de como hago el llenado de un select, espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás usando pug en tu vista debes tener un for para recorrer tu recordset que mandas como parámetro ListaUsuario.

Tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
select#usuario.form-control(autofocus, required)
  option
    for usuario in ListaUsuario
      option(value=usuario.id) #{usuario.nombre}
```

Debes de tener en cuenta que en pug es importante saber cuantos espacios o tabs existen entre cada elemento, es muy especial en cuando a identar el html.